# PSTricks set page to pixel dimensions

Tags: pstricks

I have the following PSTricks code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nopageno,pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1px}
\begin{pspicture}(-128,-128)(128,128)

  % Axes
  \psset{linewidth=2pt}
  \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
  \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape a}}
  \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape b}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

However, I want the page to be 512x512px, and the axes 256x256px and centered in the page. I'm a tex n00b so I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: use `unit=1bp` (big point)

Comment: I did that. Then I measured the length of an axis in Inkscape and still got 256pt instead of 256px. Also, this does not affect the page size, which I also want to change.

Comment: If you are using Inkscape, you are presumably generating vector graphics (e.g. PDF, EPS, SVG), so this question doesn't make sense. If you are generating PNG or JPG or something, it would make sense. Is that what you're trying to do? Raster graphics are usually measured in dimensions specified in pixels - you can scale them, but only with loss of quality (esp. if scaling up). Vector graphics aren't like that, although they may obviously not look good if scaled by too large or too small a factor. But they are not pixel-based so they scale without loss of quality.

Comment: Use the `standalone` class rather than `article`, as illustrated in one of the answers to your previous question.

Comment: Yes, I intend to export to PNG, but might use InkScape to do that because I am familiar with the tool. Or is there an easy way to do that using tex?